# Eigenvalues and -vectors of the Poisson Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, poissons-equation

We define the matrix for the discrete Poisson problem as

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 T  & -I &  0  &  \cdots &  \cdots &  \cdots & 0 \\ 
 -I &  T & -I  &    \ddots    &   &   & \vdots  \\
0 &  \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
 \vdots & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\
  \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots & 0 \\
 \vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots &\ddots & -I \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -I & T \\
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{N^2\times N^2}
\end{equation*}

with $I \in \mathbb R^{N\times N}$ being the identity matrix and $T\in \mathbb R^{N\times N}$ being a tridiagonal matrix with $4$ at main diagonal and $-1$ at the upper and sub diagonal.

So my task is to find the eigenvalues and -vectors of this matrix. I had no idea at first, so I just tried calculating them for the first few N, to see, if I could find a pattern. Unfortunately, that didn't help me. But I don't know any other way nor do I have an idea how to find those values. I'd be glad, if someone could help me here.

Comment: 1) Could you share with us some observations folllowing your calculations ?
 You say you haven't observed a pattern, but, for example, how is the range of eigenvalues increasing with $N$ ? 2) Has your lecturer said you that an explicit form exists - for the eigenvalues - for eigenvectors ?

Comment: Regarding the spectrum, have you observed that circular functions of angle $\tfrac{\pi}{N+1}$ are involved? For example, some eigenvalues have the form $4 \pm 4 \cos(\tfrac{\pi}{N+1})$. This explains why for N=3 the eigenvalues are $\{4 \pm 2\sqrt{2}, 4 \pm \sqrt{2}, 4\}$, the same for the case $N=4$ with eigenvalues $\{3 \pm \sqrt{5},  4 \pm \sqrt{5}, 5 \pm \sqrt{5}, 3,4,5\}$. For $N=5$ it is $\{4\pm2\sqrt{3}, 3\pm\sqrt{3},...\}$. But beyond $N=5$, you have to use circular functions...

Comment: I have found a very good document (http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT3350/h07/undervisningsmateriale/chap9slides.pdf) ; see in particular formulas (13) (14) (15). If you are not familiar with Kronecker product : spend some time on it : it's very important.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the help. No, our lecturer didn't tell us anything about this exercise. I will take a look at the link you've send me, but wouldn't it be a problem, if I used things we haven't been taught yet? Maybe there's another way...

Comment: What you can do is to analyze the particular cases I have given you: $N=3, N=4, N=5$. I am sure that the general case uses Kronecker product more or less.