# How to solve pentadiagonal system using Gaussian Elimination and/or Gauss Seidel

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-elimination, poissons-equation

I'm trying to solve the 2-D Poisson Equation using both Gaussian Elimination (forward elimination and back substitution) and Gauss Seidel method.

The equation is as follows:

$\ d^2u/dx^2 + d^2u/dy^2 = F(x,y)$

After discretization and applying Dirichlet boundaries for y=start and y=end and applying Neumann boundaries for x=start and x=end I ended up with a pentadiagonal coefficient matrix and a right hand side vector that is made up of F and the boundaries (only in the first and last terms of F). The following are images of the coefficient matrix, A, and the right hand side vector F:

[Coefficient Matrix A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DcBz.png)

[Right Hand Side Vector F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6LQC.png)

I have solved tridiagonal systems using both Gaussian Elimination and Gauss Seidel but I cannot figure out how I would go about doing this for this new pentadiagonal system,

$\ Au=F$             .

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. I am writing the code in MATLAB if anyone was interested.

Comment: 1) Why don't you factor this annoying factor 6.4846, in order to have a matrix with integer coefficients ? 2) As you are using Matlab (btw me too), why do you speak etc Gauss Seidel, etc.: a linear system AX=B is diectly solved by the instruction X=A\B...3)  See the recent question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2261255) and my comments.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I could factor the 6.4846 but it's not exactly necessary, right? I will do it though. I would like to use Gauss-Seidel as a learning method. I know that I can use A\F=u but that is not what I am trying to do. Any other numerical method as well would be great.

Comment: I understand now that this story of Poisson equation is not at all central (I should have read more attentively your title), but are you looking for a special implementation of Gauss Seidel that takes advantage of "pentadiagonality" ? Is it that ? If you have done it for tridiagonal matrices, where is the problem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I think I have solved it using Gauss-Seidel, but now I am trying to figure out how to plot the data properly. Could you help me with that? I have x=[0:2pi], y=[0:2pi] and u is my solution vector which is the same length as both x and y. I'm not sure how to plot this on a surface plot since u has to be a matrix and not a vector to use the surf function. Thanks

Comment: If your matrix is $n^2 \times n^2$ (here $n=4$), your solution is a $n^2 \times 1$ column vector, say $X$, that you have to "reshape" into a $n \times n$ matrix (Matlab instruction : Y=reshape(X,n,n)), and then "imagesc(Y)" with some color map.

Comment: @JeanMarie, thanks that worked well. After reshaping I was actually able to use the surf function since $X$ is now a matrix.

Comment: As Droopy, I say "I'm happy...".